# NotPetya Information and Updates

Tags: malware, ransomware

I was wondering if there were any people here who had any useful links or information on the new NotPetya attacks.

Is there any good websites to monitor attacks like this or if there are any good links to watch for more information as it becomes available.

Comment: The internet is currently full of information about it, i.e. technical sources like [arstechnica.com](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/06/a-new-ransomware-outbreak-similar-to-wcry-is-shutting-down-computers-worldwide/) or [the register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/06/27/ransomware_outbreak_hits_ukraine/) and many more all report it. I don't know what you expect apart from the information you'll find there and in the links provided there. And I'm pretty sure that you'll also find updates there quickly if there are updates. Therefore I propose to close the question as too broad.